LSD Radix for a fixed count array
I would like to create a radix LSD to sort strings. I tried to adapt to a count[27] instead of count[256], because the exercise requires it. I must use A[I][d] - 'a' + 1 for [a-z] and 0 for spaces, but it is not sorting correctly. Some strings on my tests have been duplicated. How can I solve this?
#define MAX 15
void foo(char** A, int n, int k, int max) {
  int i, d;
  char** B = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * n);

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    B[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * max);

  for (d = max - 1; d >= 0; d--) {
    int* count = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * k);
    
    for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
      count[i] = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if(A[i][d] == 32) count[0]++;
      else count[A[i][d] - 'a' + 1]++;
    }

    for (i = 1; i < k; i++)
      count[i] += count[i - 1];
    
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if(A[i][d] == 32) {
        strcpy(B[count[0] - 1], A[i]);
        count[0]--;
      }
      else {
        strcpy(B[count[A[i][d] - 'a' + 1] - 1], A[i]);
        count[A[i][d]]--;
     }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      strcpy(A[i], B[i]);

    free(count);
  }

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) free(B[i]);
  free(B);
}


What are the validity constraints on the sort inputs?  Can there be characters other than spaces and upper- and lowercase ASCII letters?  If so, then how are those supposed to affect the ordering?

And can there in fact be spaces in the inputs, other than as separators?  If so, then your method of input will not handle that, plus you have a likely issue with distinguishing between trailing spaces and trailing nothing.  If not, then why are you doing any space-related processing at all?  If you're to use exactly 27 distinct digit values with varying-length strings, then I'm inclined to guess that the 27th is supposed to be for no-character, as opposed to for the space character.

It's only allowed to pass ASCII letters to inputs. I do the lowercase part and the convert from null chars to spaces before executing foo, because it is required in my question.

The null char is necessary to be on count[0], and the rest of array count[1..n] be the letters, this is why the sum of 'a' + 1

Is MAX supposed to be the maximum number of significant characters in any input?  If so, then main() is not allocating enough space for its inputs.  Each one needs an extra byte for a string terminator.

My tests were only with strings smaller than 15. I didn't test with strings with 15 chars, but I would like to fix input.length < 15 first

Re "Some strings on my tests have been duplicated.", You didn't demo your problem. Provide a test for which it fails!

There are memory leaks (malloc with no corresponding free)

Why are you doing all those strcpy() in the sort function?  You structure the data as an array of pointers, so all you need to do is assign pointers.

@JohnBollinger nice tip! I will switch here to pointer assign directly. Thanks!

Note, ' ' and '\0' (depending on how you want to do it) should go first for proper alphabetization, cf, {"add", "added"}.

@Neil Is a good idea if I add \0 as count[0], ' ' as count[1] and [a-z] as count[2..n]?

It depends on the lexicographic order that you want them to be in; I think you are imposing a total order on a partially ordered set. At minimum, mapping to the sequence (all others including terminal, [a-z] or [A-Z]) makes sense and is in line with your code. But do you want to distinguish between ' ' and '\0' ("", " ")? Lower and upper case ("A", "a")? Accents? Sanskrit? Emojis?

@Neil It is only alphabetic letters, lowercase

This is correct: the +1 makes space for a null/space at the beginning. However, scanf is doing an arbitrary input size and reading from potentially uninitialized memory.

There are lots of stylistic and efficiency issues with the program, but I found only three actual errors:

You rely on the values of all the elements of each A[i], but you do not reliably set all of them.  Specifically, malloc() does not initialize the memory it allocates, and scanf() does not write any bytes past the string terminator.  You could fix this by allocating via calloc() instead of malloc().

You do not allocate enough space for your strings in the first place.  You rely on there being space for MAX characters plus a string terminator, but you allocate space only for MAX characters.

(Likely the issue responsible for the observed misbehavior) your sort function does not manage its count array correctly.  Specifically, this is wrong:
        count[A[i][d]]--;

It should be
        count[A[i][d] - 'a' + 1]--;




Thanks! I adjusted count[] and MAX here.
